# Mysql query returns nothing when subquery returns 0 rows

Tags: mysql, subquery

When trying to select fields from a subquery if ANY of the subqueries do not return any rows then nothing is returned (not even an empty result set)

```
SELECT sub1.field, sub2.another_field
    FROM (
        (
            SELECT field
            FROM table
            WHERE id=1
        ) AS sub1, (
            SELECT another_field
            FROM table
            WHERE id=2
        ) AS sub2
    )
```

I was hoping for a row containing a `NULL` value when a subquery return 0 rows.

Comment: It'd be better if you posted the actual code rather than (what appears to me to be) a made-up example.

Comment: At best, you would get value, value.  Worst, you get nothing as you do.  However, I would EXPECT a Cartesian, but at a MINIMUM, one of the result queries would have to return a value in order to get even 1 row returned.  Otherwise, correct with no entries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do an outer join as follows

```
SELECT sub1.field, sub2.another_field
FROM (
        SELECT field, id
        FROM tab1
        WHERE id=1
    ) AS sub1 LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT another_field, id
        FROM tab1
        WHERE id=2
    ) AS sub2
  ON sub1.id = 1 and sub2.id = 2
```

Comment: That helps, but if both subqueries don't return any rows I get nothing. (Again, I'm expecting 1 row with NULL, NULL)

Comment: Don't know how to solve that completely, but this link might help http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: Accepted as this solves the underlying problem with the original code, thanks. My answer accompanies this.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem of the query returning nothing overall when *all* subqueries return *zero rows* I've wrapped the whole lot in a `UNION` with a blank row.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT sub1.field, sub2.another_field
    FROM (
        SELECT field, id
        FROM tab1
        WHERE id=1
    ) AS sub1

    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT another_field, id
        FROM tab1
        WHERE id=2
    ) AS sub2
    ON sub1.id = 1 and sub2.id = 2

    UNION

    SELECT NULL, NULL

) AS t0
```